# Can I use a different map source other than Google Maps in Lightroom 4?

Tags: lightroom, geotagging

Google Maps are horribly outdated in my area. Is there any way to use a different map source, e.g. OpenStreetMap, inside Lightroom 4's map module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any way to modify the way that Lightroom itself displays the map.  But Google Maps apparently allows you to [make changes](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80484&topic=1687361&ctx=topic) and [fix errors](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98014&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=wiuksuwiqe8d&cbrank=1).

An alternative is to use [Jeffrey Friedl's GPS plugin for Lightroom](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/gps) which does allow you to use some other mapping sources, in a limited way.

Comment: Looks like a cannot add new buildings, though.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, no you can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

I miss some info. Do you use a GPS-tracker?

If yes, then there is absolutely no problem. Just link the GPS-data with your photos (and check the time before you start shooting on both the instruments). That is easy done in Lightroom.

If not, do yourself a favor and buy a GPS-tracker (I cannot imagine putting the photos on their spot by hand...).

Once your photos have GPS info embedded (EXIF), a lot of sites provides maps better than Google for the placements of your photos (Bing amazed me and right now Apple starts another small revolution in tracking).
I discovered this via the site of y GPS-maker.